# How to Invoke Object that's a Public Property

Tags: php

Take the following example of two classes:

```
class Yolo {
    public function __invoke() {
        echo 'YOLO';
    }
}

class Swag {
    public $yolo;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->yolo = new Yolo();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to invoke the `Yolo` object via an instance of `Swag`?
`(new Swag())->yolo();` throws a warning and doesn't call `__invoke`:

> PHP Warning:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Swag::yolo()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP 7 you can directly call it (just need extra braces):

```
((new Swag())->yolo)();
```

In PHP 5 you need a temp variable:

```
$y=(new Swag())->yolo;
$y();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you try to call the function `yolo()` on the Swag class. In your case you have to use the public class variable and call the subclass over that.

```
var_dump((new Swag())->yolo);
```

that is your object. When you use `()` you try to call the class not the class variable.

Answer (score 1):

You do not even have to make it a public method.
But you might have to reroute the call manually since the callable method is created at runtime:

```
class Yolo {
    public function __invoke() {
        echo 'YOLO';
    }
}

class Swag {
    private $yolo;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->yolo = new Yolo();
    }

    function __call($method, $args) {
          if(is_callable($this->$method))
          {
            return call_user_func_array($this->$method, $args);
          }
     }
}


(new Swag())->yolo();
```

It would probably a good idea to check first, if the called method exists and if it is actually callable.

But the example works as a proof of concept.